# characterisation of relatively compact sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$.
Why does there holds the following statement:

$A$ is relatively compact, i.e. $\overline{A}$ is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ for every sequence $(x_n)_n \subset A$ there exist a subsequence that converges in $X$

I know the fact that $M \subset X$ is compact if and only if each sequence in $M$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $M$. But why is it enough to just check seqeunces in $A$ and not in $\overline{A}$?

Comment: Approximate a sequence in $\overline A$ by one in $A$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng So for example like this: Let $x_n  \subset \overline{A}$ and define $y_n \subset A$ as follows: for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ choose $y_n \in A$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) <\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Aha! That's a good idea!

Comment: ok perfect, thank you!